# Is it possible to attach phone with USB c port to PC and 3.5mm audio out at the same time

Tags: usb-c

I have a google pixel 3. It only has a USB c port, no 3.5mm audio jack. I would like to be able to connect my phone to a PC via usb to enable adb access and at the same time get audio out of the phone with a usb c to 3.5mm jack type adaptor. I had thought that I could achieve this with an adapter like this:
[image]

However, I got one of these and while the audio output works, the usb C connection only allows charging and no data connection to the pc. I was looking at usb c hubs but I am thinking that these would only work with the phone as the host/master and the devices plugged into it as slaves.
Is there any way to achieve what I want?

The reason I want to do this is in order to use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/README.md) to remote control the phone from the pc while also getting audio out of the phone.

Comment: You can use [`scrcpy` over WiFi](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy#wireless) as a workaround (assuming you don't want to use Bluetooth audio).

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, sorry I should have mentioned in the question, but there is usually a reduction in video quality and/or lag compared to usb so I was hoping to use usb.